# nginx rewrite should be a loop

Tags: nginx, routing, rewrite

Is chatGPT bullsh!ttn me, or am I missing something obvious?

This is my question:

I have an nginx location block like this:

```
    location / {
      location ~ \.html {
        # First send it back to the start with a changed format
        rewrite /(.*) /html/$1  break;
        # Then proxy that to the S3
        proxy_pass https://MYS3.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
      }
    }
```

It should match locations ending in .html and rewrite them to have the request_uri prepended with /html/ - then proxy that request to the s3 bucket.

This works, but I don't understand why. Why would the rewritten url with the prepended /html/ not also be rewritten again and again in a loop by the same directive?

ChatGPT answered with this:

> The rewrite directive in nginx is processed in a specific order within
> the location block.
>
> When a rewrite is executed, the modified URL is processed again from
> the beginning of the location block. However, the request goes through
> the location block only once per request.
>
> In your example, the request URI is rewritten in the first rewrite
> directive to prepend /html/ to the original URI. Then, the newly
> modified URI is matched against the location block again. However,
> this time it doesn't match the location ~ .html directive because the
> modified URI now begins with /html/.
>
> Therefore, the execution flow moves forward to the proxy_pass
> directive and the request is proxied to the specified S3 bucket
> without entering into an infinite loop of rewrites.
>
> In summary, the rewritten URL is not further rewritten because it
> matches a different location block within the same location context.

I just don't understand why the rewrite directive would not happen every time, since the new URI still has '.html' in it? And chatGPT is confusing me with the idea that

> The newly modified URI is matched against the location block again ...
> this time it doesn't match the location ~ .html directive

Can't both match and not match?

Anyone here who can shine a light for me :-)

Comment: You've added `break` flag. I recommend to read [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) before asking ChatGPT.

Comment: BTW, you should add end marker (`$`) to regexp `location ~ \.html$ { ... }`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I read documentation non stop, so it's understandable that I missed something. If everyone memorized docs of every tool they used, this platform wouldn't exist. How about you explain in an answer format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `break` flag in your `rewrite` directive. [Documentation](https://nginx.org/r/rewrite) says that it work as the [break](https://nginx.org/r/break) directive:

> Stops processing the current set of `ngx_http_rewrite_module` directives.
>
> If a directive is specified inside the **location**, further processing of the request continues in **this location**.

Let's assume the request url was `/some/file.html`. So, first nginx rewrites it to `/html/some/file.html` and then act as if there was a `break` directive. That means nginx stop executing any `ngx_http_rewrite_module` directive (though there is no any in your case) and process the request in **current location**, that means it will use `proxy_pass` and will not not try to look for new `location` (that is the part where ChatGPT is wrong).

Comment: Thank you Alexey. The documentation language is confusing, but I think I'm starting to understand, no thanks to chatgpt. One final question: If I have a second rewrite after the first, also with a break, would both have an effect?

Comment: @asimovwasright if you have multiple `rewrite`s with `break` only first that match will work. That what `break` means — stop processing rewrite module directives (i.e. `rewrite`, `if`, `return`, etc.)

Comment: Great, it's clearer now :-) This question was a very simplified version of the ultimate goal,  which thanks to your help I was able to achieve. Time for a nap.